# Explaining why setting up a WiFi connection that interfaces with a virtual bridge in Linux is problematic

Tags: networking, virtualization, linux-networking, virtual-machines

> Just like you can bridge two wired ethernet interfaces, you can bridge between an ethernet interface and a wireless interface. However, most Access Points (APs) will reject frames that have a source address that didn’t authenticate with the AP.

The above comes from the Debian wiki's article on bridge network connections, and I'm trying to understand the details of why exactly this is the case. Would the following be an accurate explanation?

Suppose the following set up: one physical router which sets up an access point, one host machine with a WiFi NIC, a virtual bridge within that host, and a guest VM. The host machine and the guest VM connect to the virtual bridge. The problem is that a packet sent from the guest VM, that goes to the virtual bridge, then gets sent out by the WiFi NIC, and then reaches the access point on the router, has a source IP that is not the WiFi NIC's, correct? (Does anyone have reading suggestions delving into these topics in depth?)

Comment: (cross posted to Unix/Linux SE)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that a packet sent from the guest VM, that goes to the virtual bridge, then gets sent out by the WiFi NIC, and then reaches the access point on the router, has a source IP that is not the WiFi NIC's, correct?

Not IP. MAC address. MAC addresses are hardcoded into the network cards, but can be changed. It's what's used for switching packets on Layer 2 interfaces - and bridges are a L2 concept.

Bridges forward frames without changing them, which means that the MAC address will be the source host's MAC address, which has *not* authenticated to the AP.

Comment: I see, if I understand you correctly, a package sent from the VM states a source MAC address which is not listed in the AP's list of devices with which it can interact?

Comment: More or less correct.

Comment: How come? Am I missing the full picture? (Thanks a lot for answering by the way!)

Comment: Difficult to say from such a brief interaction, but if you grok the different layers of the protocol model the picture should be clear.